# Keras Dense function

Tags: keras

Can anyone explain me this:

```
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
```

Is it dense adding layers in the model and units in the number of neurons in the particular layer and what is reason behind the `activation` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the through Dense you add an regular densely-connected layer to the network. And as you said units specifies the number of neurons in this layer. Maybe see https://keras.io/ for more information.

The activation parameter defines which activation function is used for the units in this layer. This function takes the sum of all inputs to the neuron as input and computes through that the output for the unit (which then goes into the next unit/layer). For 'relu' it would be basically *f(x)=max(x,0)* where x is the sum of all inputs and f(x) the output.